# Routes in Laravel with or without a forward slash?

Tags: php, laravel, routes

What's the recommended approach for declaring routes: with a forward slash or is it better to leave it out? Are there any benefits to using one over the other or is it just a matter of preference?

Is it better to use this:

```
 Route::get('/read', function(){
        $user = User::findOrFail(1);
            return $user;
    });
```

Or this instead:

```
Route::get('read', function(){
    $user = User::findOrFail(1);
        return $user;
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a preference thing; there may be some server architecture where it makes a difference, but I haven't come across anything like that. Personally I use with `"/"`, as it's easier for me to read, and I don't like how `Route::get("", ...);` looks vs `Route::get("/", ...);`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It comes down to preference. When passing the route, it actually trims the forward slashes off, then formats it properly. In Illuminate/Routing/Router.php, all routes go through the `prefix` function, which looks like this:

```
protected function prefix($uri)
{
    return trim(trim($this->getLastGroupPrefix(), '/').'/'.trim($uri, '/'), '/') ?: '/';
}
```

So if you create a group prefix `/test/` and and a uri of `/route`, it becomes `test/route`