# Slashes in Laravel Routes

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-7, laravel-route

I'm new to Laravel and was wondering what is the significance and meaning of using forward slashes in routes? For example:

```
Route::get('/welcome', 'MyController@welcome');
```

I get the same result with:

```
Route::get('welcome', 'MyController@welcome');
```

So what is the difference? Is the forward slash at the beginning always optional, or is it necessary sometimes?

Also, can multiple forward slashes be used, e.g.:

```
Route::get('/welcome/to/this/subpath', 'MyController@welcome');
```

Just trying to learn. Thanks for your insights.

Comment: It's optional and yes you can use multiple slashes in your routes

Comment: See **aynber** answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50935628/4575350

Comment: Thanks STA, that link was helpful. I will close this question now.